# How to load model data when starting rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How to load model data when starting rails app

I have meta data stored in the data base.

what I want is to load all the meta data (eg myModel.all) on rails start up and assign it to a global variable so that the meta data is available to all view pages.

How to do this?
Please tell in simple steps.

Comment: Have a look at this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

Comment: You need to show research effort before posting here. You should probably follow a basic rail tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

```
# config/initializers/meta_data.rb
ALL_ZE_META_DATA = Meta.all
```

Put it into an [Initializer](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html)